# Log4j doesn't log anything under JBoss 6 EAP

Tags: java, log4j, jboss-eap-6

I saw several questions on the topic, but since they are rather related to errors I don't think this is a duplicate.

My problem is that I can't get any logging out of a .war I'm deploying on JBoss 6 EAP, there are no errors logged also however. There is also a file named as my .war created under the /log folder in JBoss, but it is also empty.

The .war deploys fine and works. Since I'm using Spring I can't even see it initializing it's contexts.

Logging works perfectly under Tomcat 7 with the same .war.

I have created a log4j.xml and placed it in my WEB-INF/classes dir (I also tried in /WEB-INF):

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <root> 
    <priority value ="info" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I'm using log4j 1.2.17, Spring 3.1 and JBoss 6 EAP.

Any help greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814498/log4j-logger-messages-are-not-displayed-on-jboss-webapp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12039763/use-my-log4j-under-jboss-6

Answer (score 20):

Unlike JBoss AS 7.1.1, JBoss EAP 6 activates per-deployment logging configuration if it finds [a logging config file](https://community.jboss.org/message/736873#736873):  https://community.jboss.org/message/776182#776182

I suggest removing `log4j.xml`.  If that doesn't help, modify your jboss configuration to set the system property `org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment` to `false`.  In my case, I had to add this line to `standalone.conf`:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"
```

Comment: It switches off configuration which is defined in application, so it's a workaround but not a solution, right?

Comment: worked for me! JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false"

Comment: if you remove log4j.xml where do you get you own configuration from ?

Comment: @Tom the configuration lives in the logging section of EAP's `standalone.xml`, so you would need to customise the log configuration there.

Comment: I have managed to use a log4j2.xml config file. Now it works fine, I had to put the file into subProject/properties/... This way I have the regular server logging and my specific app logging in a separate file.

Comment: I had the same problem with the supposed logging produced by Liferay 6.2, and when I put the property on JBoss immediately the log appears. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In my case, EAP 6.0 in domain mode, I had to set org.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment = false as an environment property for the specific server. Setting it as a "System Property" as stated in the EAP 6.3 docs did not work.