# Error listenerStart in Jboss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I am using JBoss 7. It is spring hibernate application. I am getting

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
```

when I restart my JBoss. Earlier I have this issue in tomcat but it is resolved by adding `logging.porpeties` in classes folder. I am able to see which listener is causing issue in tomcat. But in JBoss I don't have any clue how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: if you are using JBoss EAP 6 or AS 7.1.2+ and not getting much logging, it may help to specify the system property `-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14575830/14379

The problem is that "Error listenerStart" is a very generic error message.  It is supposed to be preceded by other, more helpful error messages, but in some cases it isn't.

Other [people](https://community.jboss.org/message/762525#762525) have solved the logging problem by removing `log4j.properties` from the war file or a jar inside it, so try leaving out `log4j.properties` when deploying on JBoss AS 7.

In my case, there was no `log4j.properties` to remove.  The only workaround I have found is to set a breakpoint in `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart()` where it calls `getLogger().error()`, and then run JBoss in debug mode while deploying my war file.  Then I can inspect the `Throwable` to see what went wrong.

In Eclipse, I have configured a Debug Detail Formatter (in Preferences) for `java.lang.Throwable` which returns the stack trace:

```
java.io.StringWriter sw = new java.io.StringWriter();
this.printStackTrace(new java.io.PrintWriter(sw));
return sw.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying an EAR, try deploying the WAR alone, as JBoss will show more information about the error.

Comment: I miss to specify that i try to deploy WAR in Jboss and not EAR. It is only showing Error listenerstart