# JBoss multiple SLF4J bindings error

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am using JBoss 6 and am getting a multiple versions error when trying to run my application:

> ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>
> ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Found binding in
> [vfs:/C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Found binding in
> [vfs:/C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/newsroom-integration-persistence-service.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

My application declares slf4j-log4j12 in the pom but not slf4j-jboss-logmanager so have no idea why its trying to use this. This is the pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? It seems to be causing 'DEBUG' level errors to be written to the console even when the level-name set in jboss-logging.xml is set to INFO!!

Comment: You should try looking at using jboss-deployment-structure.xml to exclude built in module. There was a similar thread in stackoverflow at [configuring logging with jboss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863630/how-to-step-by-step-configure-logging-in-jboss-6-x-with-log4j-in-java/18981756#18981756)

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter what you declare in your `pom.xml`, JBoss is going to load what's in its common classpath.  If you prefer to use the `log4j` binding, then you have to remove `C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar`.  This is the approach recommended by [Alfresco](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Falf-jboss-config-SLF4J.html).  Quoting:

> You may see the following errors during the startup:
>
> 2011-10-12 10:47:21,505 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
>
> 2011-10-12 10:47:21,505 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: Found binding in [vfszip:/usr/local/jeap51/jboss-
>   as/common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logging.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> 2011-10-12 10:47:21,505 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: Found binding in [vfszip:/usr/local/jeap51/jboss
>   -as/server/W51J51I1/deploy/alfresco.war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>
> 2011-10-12 10:47:21,505 ERROR [STDERR] (main) SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
>
> To avoid these errors, remove the /common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logging.jar file.

Comment: Thanks for response @davidfmatheson. I tried removing slf4j-jboss-logmanager.jar from that location but it now gives this error: `DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/quartz-ra.rar" is in error due to the following reason(s): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder from BaseClassLoader@1a78424{vfs:///C:/jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/conf/jboss-service.xml}`

Comment: This actually solved my sf4j dependency hell on jboss. Thanks!